# GeoWebCache Upgrade Error

Tags: installation, java, geowebcache

I'm attempting to upgrade to a new version of GeoWebCache from 1.3.  I'm trying to upgrade to version 1.7.2.  I blew away the geowebcache directory under the Tomcat webapps and also deleted the geowebcache directory under Tomcat work.  I put the new WAR file in the Tomcat webapps directory and can not get it to start correctly.  I've been looking all over trying to see if anyone ran into this issue with no luck.  The server has Java 1.6 installed on it and according to the GWC documentation it supports 1.5 or later.

Here are the snippets from the stack trace.

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restFilterInvocationInterceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/acegi-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'restFilterDefinitionMap' while setting bean property 'objectDefinitionSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.geowebcache.security.RESTfulDefinitionSource] for bean with name 'restFilterDefinitionMap' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/acegi-config.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/geowebcache/security/RESTfulDefinitionSource : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class org.geowebcache.security.RESTfulDefinitionSource)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)

...

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.geowebcache.security.RESTfulDefinitionSource] for bean with name 'restFilterDefinitionMap' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/acegi-config.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/geowebcache/security/RESTfulDefinitionSource : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class org.geowebcache.security.RESTfulDefinitionSource)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1265)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:433)

...

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/geowebcache/security/RESTfulDefinitionSource : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class org.geowebcache.security.RESTfulDefinitionSource)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2822)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick google of `Unsupported major.minor version 51.0` leads to [How to fix: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-error). Basically you need Java 7 for recent versions of GeoWebCache (and GeoServer and other GeoTools based tools), you will need Java 8 for future releases.

Comment: I wish it were that simple. I tried upgrading to Java 7 earlier with the same behavior.  I tried both the JRE and the JDK for Java 7. Also, 51.0 indicates that Java 7 isn't supported. Something else isn't right here...

Comment: Maybe some thing else is broken but you need to edit the question to show the error after you run with Java 7.

Comment: Thanks iant.  The Tomcat Service configured on the machine was configured to use Java 6. That was the issue and Java 7 was able to help me get around that.